# Array in Powershell - Cant read each value by corresponding with a second array

Tags: arrays, powershell, loops, multidimensional-array, foreach

I'm working on a project,

I have 3 arrays, and i want to take all values from it. maybe some code would be better than explanation.

```
$Array1= "Value1", "Value2", ....
$Array2= "Another1", "Another2",...
$Array3= "Again1", "Again2", ...
```

My result should be

```
Value1 Another1 Again1
Value2 Another2 Again2
```

etc...

I've tried many option like so :

```
foreach($i in $Array1){
  Foreach($j in $Value2){
     Write-host $i "," $j
   }
} 

result:
Value1, Another1
Value1,Another2
Value2,Another1
Value2,Another2
```

I've search a solution for like 5 hours . and i'm not an expert in powershell.
please help me !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure either all arrays have the same number of elements, or take the minimum amount of elements to loop through:

```
$Array1= "Value1", "Value2" #
$Array2= "Another1", "Another2"#
$Array3= "Again1", "Again2"#

# make sure you do not step out of index on one of the arrays
$items = [math]::Min($Array1.Count, [math]::Min($Array2.Count, $Array3.Count))

for ($i = 0; $i -lt $items; $i++) {
    # using the -f Format operator gives nice-looking code I think
    '{0},{1},{2}' -f $Array1[$i], $Array2[$i], $Array3[$i]
}
```

Result:

```
Value1,Another1,Again1
Value2,Another2,Again2
```